# Which VPS is best ? SSD VPS or HDD VPS?

Tags: web-hosting, server, vps

Some years back when I began working in the SSD VPS business I didn’t recognize what an “area name” is, yet what a SSD is. It was two years prior when I first found out about SSD and I’m almost certain there are numerous as myself pondering what is a SSD, what is the distinction between a SSD hosting arrangement and a HDD arrange and which one is best for their site.

Answer (score 3):

Well that's an obvious one, SSD (solid state drive) is way faster than conventional rotating disks HDD.

Read, seek times are faster.

For hosting purposes SSD is a great solution. That way you can actually not keep everything in the RAM and have quite high read/write speeds to disk.

Problem with SSD is that they cost more, so you will have less disk space for same money.

Comment: The price difference between an HDD and SSD is less than it used to be, so you probably just wanna go with an SSD for hosting - the couple dollars difference shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards Well I use vultr and ramnode for my VPS, both rely on SSD, have never looked back.